# Why do I get a certificate "error" in Firefox ONLY?

Tags: firefox, ssl

I have a small LAN with:

1. A Synology server where I have installed a Comodo Wildcard
   Certificate for mydomain.com.
2. Three wired clients running Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 10 Pro, and
   one wireless client running Mac OSX.
3. This LAN is connected via an IPSEC VPN to another remote LAN with
   more clients.

**My issue:**

When I try to connect to my Synology box using https:// from a LOCAL client, using Internet Explorer 11 or Google Chrome, everything works fine.  The browsers see that the website has a valid SSL Certificate and I get no errors or warnings of any kind.

However, when I use Firefox, the certificate doesn't work at all, with the following symptoms:

1. For **THREE Wired Clients on LAN using Windows 8.1 Pro/Windows 10 Pro and Firefox:**

   "The Connection is Untrusted" If I click on the little Globe next to the Address bar it says "The website does not supply identity information.  Your connection to this website is not encrypted."
2. For **Wireless Client on LAN using OSX and Firefox:**

   EVERYTHING WORKS FINE.  If I click the lock next to the address bar in Firefox it correctly shows that the website is verified by COMODO.
3. For **Wired Client on another LAN running Windows 7 and connecting via VPN and Firefox:**

   EVERYTHING WORKS FINE.

So in summary: I can connect via HTTPS using Internet Explorer or Chrome from ANYWHERE with no problems.  I only have problems with FIREFOX on SPECIFIC MACHINES.  It is like they aren't seeing the certificate AT ALL.  What is something I could look at here?

Note that on the Windows 10 Pro machine, it is a BRAND NEW FRESH install.  There is nothing else on the machine except browsers.  This is a brand new fresh install of the latest Windows with the latest Firefox.

Comment: Is that all it says in Firefox? No additional error messages, about outdated encryption standards, an untrusted certificate in the chain, something like that?

Comment: I'm going to leave this here in case someone else has the same or similar problem:

I had installed my private key and certificate on the Synology server, but not the Intermediate Certificates.  Apparently, Firefox maintains a separate Certificate Store from IE and Chrome, which already come with the necessary Comodo Intermediates. On some machines, Firefox already had the necessary Intermediates, from other sites that had provided them, but on these other machines where Firefox was rarely used, it was basically a blank slate.  After installing Intermediates on the server, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to leave this here in case someone else has the same or similar problem:

I had installed my private key and certificate on the Synology server, but had failed to include the Intermediate Certificates in the package.

Apparently, Firefox maintains a separate Certificate Store from IE and Chrome, which already come with the necessary Comodo Intermediates.

On some machines, Firefox already had the necessary Intermediates, from other sites that had provided them, but on these other machines where Firefox was rarely used, it was basically a blank slate. After installing Intermediates Certificates on the Synology server, everything was fine.